# How to batch resize PNG files with commandline on Mac?

Tags: image-resizing

I want to resize a folder of PNG images to a specified scaled size like (50%) on Mac. What is the easiest way to do that with commandline?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just install [Imagemagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php) then you will be able to use **convert** and **mogrify** commands which do that sort of things easily.

Answer (score 5):

The ImageMagick command you need is `mogrify` if you want to do a whole directory (folder) full of images.

```
# First, check current sizes of PNGs
identify *png
a.png PNG 2480x3508 2480x3508+0+0 8-bit sRGB 25.4KB 0.000u 0:00.009
b-0.png[1] PNG 2480x3508 2480x3508+0+0 8-bit sRGB 2c 2.18KB 0.000u 0:00.000
b-1.png[2] PNG 2480x3508 2480x3508+0+0 8-bit sRGB 2c 2.2KB 0.000u 0:00.000

# Now reduce those puppies in half
mogrify -resize 50x50% *png

# Re-check their sizes
identify *png
a.png PNG 1240x1754 1240x1754+0+0 8-bit sRGB 1.42KB 0.000u 0:00.000
b-0.png[1] PNG 1240x1754 1240x1754+0+0 8-bit sRGB 2c 1.43KB 0.000u 0:00.000
b-1.png[2] PNG 1240x1754 1240x1754+0+0 8-bit sRGB 2c 1.46KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

**Updated**

If you want to do fancier things, you may prefer to use a little loop:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob
for f in *.png; do
   new=${f/.png/thumb.png}
   echo convert "$f" -resize 50x50% "$new"
done
```

So, this will loop through all PNG files and calculate a new name for each (in the variable `new`) and then use ImageMagick's `convert` to resize the images and save with the new name.

Back up your images first and if you like the way it works, remove the word `echo` from the second to last line to make it actually do anything rather than just tell you what it plans to do.

Comment: How do I control the output of the filename to be *.thumb.png rather than replacing the original files? Thanks

Comment: Have another look now please.

Comment: Did this work out for you? If so, maybe reconsider which is the better answer.